# Render Modal for Dynamic Table in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a dynamic table whose items I render through a list. The idea is that, on clicking the name of a row, a modal will open and that will print certain values retrieved from the backend server.

When I click on a specific person's name, the modal loads for all elements in the table. How do I fix this?

The rendered code for the table is as follows:-

```
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S. NO.</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>ADDRESS</th>
      <th>TELEPHONE</th>
      <th>EMAIL</th>
      <th>AGE</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.state.personData.map((pRow, idx) => (
    <>
      <PopUp hideModal={this.hideModal} show={this.state.show} id={siteRow.id} />

      <tr key={pRow.id}>
        <td>{idx + 1}</td>
        <td> <a onClick={this.showModal}> {pRow.name} </a> </td>
        <td>{pRow.address}</td>
        <td>{pRow.phone}</td>
        <td>{pRow.email}</td>
        <td>{pRow.age}</td>
        <td>
          {" "}
          <DeleteButton id={pRow.id} onDelete={this.onDelete} />{" "}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the code for the table, the placement of the PopUp component is such because I want to pass the ID of the particular site to the modal.

This is the rendered code for the modal:-

```
showModal(e) {
    this.setState({
      show: true
    });
}

hideModal(e) {
  this.setState({
    show:false
    });
  this.props.hideModal && this.props.hideModal(e);
}

render() {
  if(!this.props.show){
     return null;
  }

return (
 <>
  <div>
    The ID of the person is: {this.props.id}
    <button type="button" className="btn theButton" onClick={this.hideModal}>CLOSE</button>
  </div>
 </>
);
```

}

This is very rudimentary code and I haven't added much CSS so this just opens up in the table itself. I want to change this but given the placement of the PopUp component and the fact that I want to pass the ID to the component, I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a series of `Popup`s, but only a variable controlling their visibility. Consider replacing the `show` state as a simple visibility with a `showId` one, meant as the "id" of the `Popup` to be shown.

```
showModal(id) {
    this.setState({
      showId: id
    });
}

hideModal(e) {
  this.setState({
    showId: null
    });
  this.props.hideModal && this.props.hideModal(e);
}
```

Then:

```
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S. NO.</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>ADDRESS</th>
      <th>TELEPHONE</th>
      <th>EMAIL</th>
      <th>AGE</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.state.personData.map((pRow, idx) => (
    <>
      <PopUp hideModal={this.hideModal} show={this.state.showId === pRow.id} id={siteRow.id} />

      <tr key={pRow.id}>
        <td>{idx + 1}</td>
        <td> <a onClick={() => this.showModal(pRow.id)}> {pRow.name} </a> </td>
        <td>{pRow.address}</td>
        <td>{pRow.phone}</td>
        <td>{pRow.email}</td>
        <td>{pRow.age}</td>
        <td>
          {" "}
          <DeleteButton id={pRow.id} onDelete={this.onDelete} />{" "}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I did not try the code, but I think it should work.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Incidentally, do you have any idea as to how I can load this PopUp component as a proper modal? Right now, the modal opens up inside the table because that is where it is placed and I've placed it there because I want to be able to pass person ID

Comment: Well, often the suggestion is to place the Popup "inline", and it has a resons to say that. However, I think the very best way to deal with it is via "Portal", that is the Modal and its content should appear _outside_ the normal node tree. Not trivial if you have a little experience, though: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html